# Java polymorphism top level method is called

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding

I have an inherited object in a java project and I am trying to call the overriden method in the child object. For some reason the parent version of the method is being called. It was my understanding of polymorphism that the lowest version of a method is always called. Why is the parent version being called?

```
public class Generator
{
    public static void acceptPending()
    {
        System.out.println("top level is called");
    }
}

public class GeneratorNeo extends Generator
{
    public static void acceptPending()
    {
        System.out.println("neo level is called");
    }
}

public class Driver()
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Generator gen = null;
        gen = new GeneratorNeo();
        gen.acceptPending(); // prints top level is called
    }
}
```

Comment: If I recall correctly you can’t override static methods - trying adding the @Override annotation to the child classes method and see what you get

Answer (score 5, accepted):

acceptPending is a static method, **static methods are called based on the compile time type of the object** ie Parent type. unlike instance methods.

so removing static keywords from both classes would give you the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Generator {
    public void acceptPending() {
        System.out.println("top level is called");
    }
}

public class GeneratorNeo extends Generator {
    @Override
    public void acceptPending() {
        System.out.println("neo level is called");
    }
}

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Generator gen = null;
        gen = new GeneratorNeo();
        gen.acceptPending(); // prints neo level is called
    }
}
```